# Turn off HDMI on Musl Aarch64 OS

Tags: hdmi, openwrt

### Objective

I want to turn off HDMI on my Raspberry Pi 3 Model B. The binaries for Raspbian does not work on my OS because it is linked to a different standard c library. Before I go down the rabbit hole I need to ask, what is the line of least resistance?

- Do arm6hf or aarch64 binaries for musl exist?
- Are there other ways of turning off HDMI without using tvservice?

### Attempt

There were many steps to compile and I guessed some of it along the way. I don't have much experience with cmake either, so I could have made mistakes.

I got the source from [github.com/raspberrypi/userland/](https://github.com/raspberrypi/userland/tree/master/host_applications/linux/apps/tvservice) and compiled tvservice for musl-aarch64 using a docker cross-compiler based on [these instructions](https://budevg.github.io/posts/docker/2018/08/02/docker-cross-compile.html). I was not able to compile everything defined in `userland/buildme` script, so I changed cmake to this line:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=$BUILDTYPE -DARM64=$ARCH --target host_applications/linux ../../..
```

The target parameter seemed to work! I checked the binary type and linked libraries to make sure everything looked right.

```
# file tvservice
tvservice: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-musl-aarch64.so.1, not stripped
# ldd tvservice
    /lib/ld-musl-aarch64.so.1 (0x4000000000)
    libvchiq_arm.so => /opt/userland/build/lib/libvchiq_arm.so (0x40008c7000)
    libvcos.so => /opt/userland/build/lib/libvcos.so (0x40008df000)
    libc.musl-aarch64.so.1 => /lib/ld-musl-aarch64.so.1 (0x4000000000)
```

Next I moved the build output directory (`/opt/userland/build`) from my container to my Raspberry Pi. After moving and executing the linked libraries were not found. I tried setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` but it did not help, so I moved the libraries `libvchiq_arm.so` and `libvcos.so` to `/lib/` (on OpenWRT  `/lib64` is syblinked to `/lib`). I ran `tvservice -o` again and it just hanged with no errors or any output.

I don't have much experience with GDB (GNU Debugger). Not sure if that's the right way forward. I am using a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B with OpenWRT, however, I'm looking for a solution that will work with any Raspberry Pi on any musl based OS like Apline/Void.

PS: I wanted to add these tags: `musl, apline, tvservice` but I don't have enough reputation.